# Angular Ui grid disabling auto Resizing

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I use auto resizing in angular ui-grid as described in
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing

I want to enable/disable auto resizing, but I cannot find any configuration option for it. https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options

So I want to define:

```
 GridOptions = {                              
            enableAutoResizing: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you're looking for is the auto-resize syntax in the gridOptions object:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data:myData, autoResize:true };
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use code to turn it off dynamically and gridOptions does not have a flag to disable it without removing the directive attribute entirely.

Your best option might be to create your own custom directive that wraps the ui-grid directive and pass in whether or not to attach the ui-grid-auto-resize attribute to angular-ui-grid's own directive (and any other directives you may wish to use/not use).

All of the following attributes could be dynamically added or removed from your own custom wrapper directive:

```
<div data-ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" data-ui-grid-edit data-ui-grid-cellnav data-ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-grouping></div>
```